# Macbook Pro crashes when using simulator - AegirPoster process

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, simulator

recently my MacBook start crashing while using the simulator. I am developing an app in SwiftUI and I thought that might be my app that is the problem.
Then I realised that it happens with all the apps that I have, even with a blank one.
I reinstalled Xcode and the simulators - no success.
in the crash logs it says "AegirPoster" process crashed the simulator.
From the little information that I found this might be related to the lock screen or the weather app of the simulator.
Any ideas how to prevent it from crashing my MacBook?
Here is a part of the rash report:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 05BE6CEF-6B5E-4D49-8704-7410B14083AF
CrashReporter Key:   D1AA8254-BD20-324C-D6CA-6AD2A866EE52
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,1
Process:             AegirPoster [1121]
Path:                /Volumes/VOLUME/*/AegirProxyApp.app/PlugIns/AegirPoster.appex/AegirPoster
Identifier:          com.apple.NanoUniverse.AegirProxyApp.AegirPoster
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [918]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC51AD5-9534-4D08-BADD-A60BE0496A51 [1011]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [911]

Date/Time:           2023-09-11 07:29:14.6119 -0600
Launch Time:         2023-09-11 07:29:10.5790 -0600
OS Version:          macOS 13.5.2 (22G91)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: AegirPoster [1121]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10dd08fe8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10dda312c pthread_kill + 256
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x10d9565ec abort + 104
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x10d955a6c __assert_rtn + 268
4   NanoUniverse                           0x102b6add4 -[NUNICalliopeResourceManager _generatePipelineVshName:fshName:config:blend0:blend1:pixelFormat0:pixelFormat1:].cold.1 + 40
5   NanoUniverse                           0x102b45d98 -[NUNICalliopeResourceManager _generatePipelineVshName:fshName:config:blend0:blend1:pixelFormat0:pixelFormat1:] + 936
6   NanoUniverse                           0x102b457c4 -[NUNICalliopeResourceManager renderOffscreenPipelineForSpheroid:layer:config:] + 176
7   NanoUniverse                           0x102b41cb0 -[NUNICalliopeRenderer _renderPatchSpheroid:frustumCullingState:drawableSize:frameBufferIndex:renderEncoder:] + 2752
8   NanoUniverse                           0x102b4310c -[NUNICalliopeRenderer _renderOffscreenSceneWithScene:spheroids:viewport:commandBuffer:frameBufferIndex:drawableTexture:] + 1752
9   NanoUniverse                           0x102b43edc -[NUNICalliopeRenderer renderWithScene:viewport:commandBuffer:passDescriptor:] + 252
10  NanoUniverse                           0x102b3f430 -[NUNIQuad renderWithCommandBuffer:passDescriptor:] + 108
11  ClockKitUI                             0x10236bb70 -[CLKUIMetalQuadView _renderQuads:toScreenWithCommandBuffer:passDescriptor:] + 332
12  ClockKitUI                             0x10236ad78 -[CLKUIMetalQuadView _snapshotTextureInRect:scale:time:withAdditionalPasses:] + 1800
13  ClockKitUI                             0x10236a270 __48-[CLKUIMetalQuadView snapshotInRect:scale:time:]_block_invoke + 556
14  ClockKitUI                             0x102341488 -[CLKUIQuadView _runOnRenderQueueIfNeeded:] + 136
15  ClockKitUI                             0x102369f40 -[CLKUIMetalQuadView snapshotInRect:scale:time:] + 268
16  AegirPoster                            0x102259058 0x102234000 + 151640
17  AegirPoster                            0x102251844 0x102234000 + 120900
18  AegirPoster                            0x102251018 0x102234000 + 118808
19  AegirPoster                            0x10225966c 0x102234000 + 153196
20  AegirPoster                            0x1022734b8 0x102234000 + 259256
21  AegirPoster                            0x102273808 0x102234000 + 260104
22  PosterKit                              0x103912098 -[PRRenderer scene:willConnectToSession:options:] + 432
23  UIKitCore                              0x114a2bdd0 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1012
24  UIKitCore                              0x1155053b4 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 804
25  UIKitCore                              0x11550569c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 356
26  UIKitCore                              0x114ffc77c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 260
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x118c88014 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 296
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x118cb0acc __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.82 + 224
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x118c94bb4 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 160
30  FrontBoardServices                     0x118cb0844 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 284
31  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10da7fd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
32  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10da83c4c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 376
33  FrontBoardServices                     0x118cd3fa0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 44
34  FrontBoardServices                     0x118cd3e7c -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 196
35  FrontBoardServices                     0x118cd3fd4 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
36  CoreFoundation                         0x10438d69c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
37  CoreFoundation                         0x10438d5e4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 172
38  CoreFoundation                         0x10438cd54 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 232
39  CoreFoundation                         0x10438743c __CFRunLoopRun + 768
40  CoreFoundation                         0x104386d28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
41  GraphicsServices                       0x118487bc0 GSEventRunModal + 160
42  UIKitCore                              0x115504054 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
43  UIKitCore                              0x115507ccc UIApplicationMain + 124
44  ExtensionKit                           0x1032b9758 -[_EXRunningUISceneExtension startWithArguments:count:] + 284
45  ExtensionFoundation                    0x1035d3f20 EXExtensionMain + 216
46  Foundation                             0x10b4f7348 NSExtensionMain + 176
47  dyld_sim                               0x102401558 start_sim + 20
48  dyld
```

Comment: I believe you should ask more precise question about what is causing the crash on you system and how to prevent it. Please look at my answer. I’m pretty sure that Xcode Simulator in latest version of Xcode is the reason of the problems.

Comment: We are seeing this on 5-10 of our CI builds on PR's with Xcode 15 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Xcode Beta 15?

I found out that AegirPoster is one of the few other processes which can crash in all latest beta versions of Xcode Simulator. Those processes are started by SimulatorTrampoline process. See your crash report:

```
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [911]
```

I'm testing Xcode Beta 15.0 since first version and those crashes keeps happening very often. The worse fact is that running Simulator app keeps CPU usage very high - even on idle. You can follow this thread on Apple Developer forums to see more people dealing with similar issues:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734573

Answer (score 0):

Not quite shure but https://mroi.github.io/apple-internals/
you find the path to astronomy watch face and lock screen on; /System/Library/CoreServices/AegirProxyApp.app

In Xcode think the problem arise as a compatibility problem:
watchOS 10.0 beta 8 (21R5355a) Simulator (Installed) but not compatible with Xcode 15
So either update or Remove all not compatible and restart Mac .
Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I don't quite understand how to remove the ones which are not compatible? I don't have any watchOS runtime installed. Could you give me some more details?

Comment: Try and have a look if missing
System/Library/CoreServices/AegirProxyApp.app/AegirProxyApp;

Comment: I checked and it is definitely not there. How can I add it? Is there any chance? I have  all of the latest runtime environments installed

Comment: I changed to M1 processor with Sonoma and with Xcode I also now get the Aegirposter fallout on simulator. I can not myself figure out why the wallpapper is causing problems.
Here in Xcode/Settings you will find the version installed. Try install  betaversion 15.1 Beta 3
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_1-release-notes

You might be using a different command line Tool.
You can also see it in Right Click on Xcode.app and go into Contents/version.plist

Comment: Or Try this its a fix to create a plist file in the simulator runtime:
From: https://blog.nihongo-app.com/stop-xcode-14-beta-from-pegging-cpu/

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Library/Wallpaper/Collections/Collections.plist -c "add order array" -c "add order: string 23EC2CF1-0188-49FC-B214-EC1AB37FE5C4"

Comment: It turned out that I have a hardware issue and I had my motherboard replaced by the local Apple service. After replacement I got everything running smooth. Thanks for all the suggestions